# Is using a date as a schema key in Mongoose for a non-date value possible?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was trying to use a `date` key in a **mongoose Schema** without a `Date` as value. However it turn out that it erased my value and replaced it with a `"1970-01-01T00:00:01.994Z"` value !

Here's a sample of my schema :

```
mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    date: [Number],
    dates: [Number]
},{collection:"myCollection"});
```

The date key is retrieved as a `Date string` at UTC 0 whatever given (an Array of numbers in my case), the dates key however is perfectly displayed when used !

Couldn't find any reference of this in [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), maybe I haven't searched at the right place (not a great English speaker/reader) or maybe there's something else, who knows ?

Thanks

Comment: paste sample data that you are trying to save and the resulting saved object

Comment: @ifiok I forgot a paragraph ! About sample data if my document contains ``date: [2009,2010]`` it will erase and replace it by ``date: "1970-01-01T00:00:01.994Z"`` but not if I use dates instead of date

Comment: It is not good practice to use SchemaType as the key. It would be wise from using them as they are usually reserved keywords such as String, Date, Boolean, etc

Comment: @ifiok isn't that case sensitive ? as ``"Date" != "date"``